# JsonConvert SerializeObject with Func property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, json.net

My Razor view I have template Like bellow

```
@helper EditLink(SampleEmployeeModel data)
    {
    <b>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id =data.ID }, new { @class = "modal_link" })
    </b>
}
```

Then I am using this template in my Grid control like bellow. The Grid Helper method worked based on [JQuertDataTable](https://www.datatables.net/) .

```
@(
        Html.Grid<SampleEmployeeModel>()
        .SetName("GridEmployeeServerSide")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(b => b.ID).EnableSearch(false); 
            columns.Bound().Template(o => EditLink(o)).SetTitle("Edit");
        })
        .Pageable(a => a.SetPageType(PageType.full_numbers))
        .DataSource(a =>
        {
            a.Read(read => read.Action("RRDLDataTableAjaxData"));
            a.ServerSideProcessing(true);
        })
    )
```

the RRDLDataTableAjaxData should return the record like bellow

```
 [
    {"ID":1,"Edit":"<b>\r\n<a class=\"modal_link\" href=\"/Samples/Edit/1\">Edit</a>\r\n</b>\r\n"},
    {"ID":2,"Edit":"<b>\r\n<a class=\"modal_link\" href=\"/Samples/Edit/2\">Edit</a>\r\n</b>\r\n"},
    {"ID":3,"Edit":"<b>\r\n<a class=\"modal_link\" href=\"/Samples/Edit/3\">Edit</a>\r\n</b>\r\n"}
 ]
```

I am getting expected result when grid load very first time, If I go to 2nd page it not return expected JSon.

How the Helper method generate HTML Grid is
It write the bellow code into Razor view

```
 <table class="table table-striped nowrap dt-responsive" data-rrdl-grid="" id="RRDLGrid21V52" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <TH></TH>  
                <TH></TH>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table> 

    <script type='text/javascript'>
    var dataTable_GridEmployeeServerSide_Option =  {
  "columns": [
    {
      "targets": 1,
      "defaultContent": "",
      "data": "ID",
      "title": "ID",
      "visible": true
    },   
    {
      "targets": 2,
      "defaultContent": "",
      "data": "Edit",
      "searchable": true,
      "title": "Edit",
      "visible": true
    }
  ],
  "dom": "<'table-header-row' <'dom-left' ><'dom-center' ><'dom-right' lp>>t",
  "autoWidth": false,
  "deferRender": true,
  "info": false,
  "lengthChange": false,
  "ordering": true,
  "paging": true,
  "processing": false,
  "searching": false,
  "serverSide": true,
  "stateSave": false,
  "ajax": {
    "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "url": "../Samples/RRDLDataTableAjaxData",
    "dataType": "json",
    "dataSrc": "data"
  },
  "destroy": false,
  "orderClasses": false,
  "orderMulti": false,
  "pageLength": 10,
  "pagingType": "full_numbers",
  "scrollCollapse": false,
  "language": {
    "paginate": {
      "first": "<i class=\"icon-left\"></i><i class=\"icon-left\"></i>",
      "last": "<i class=\"icon-right\"></i><i class=\"icon-right\"></i>",
      "next": "<i class=\"icon-right\"></i>",
      "previous": "<i class=\"icon-left\"></i>"
    }
  },
  "OddRowColor": null,
  "EvenRowColor": null,
  "FixedRowHeight": 0,
  "HighlightSearchText": false,
  "SelectCheckBox": false,
  "RowTemplate": null
}
    $(document).ready(function () {
_DataTable(GridEmployeeServerSide);}
)
    </script>
```

My Question is How to pass **EditLink** into helper server when user click 2 nd page.

Comment: You can't serialize a delegate.

Comment: Actually I want to serialize the mvc Server side  Razor template into Json Is any other way to do that.

Comment: What would that even mean? Templates aren't objects.

Answer (score 0):

The error is showing different property responsible for error. Clearly it's `ApplicationInstance` which is causing the circular reference. and It has nothing to do with code snippet provided.

According to Json.Net documentation you can avoid circular reference problem using below setting:

```
var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects
};
```

Comment: I am getting error like bellow
Cannot serialize delegates over unmanaged function pointers, dynamic methods or methods outside the delegate creator's assembly.